# Call Java from JavaScript gwt

Tags: java, gwt

Hi I have the following strange issue:

I have gwt application. it contains 3 image widgets and a button. on Button click I am 
calling function X() and then inside X I am calling Test(testscan instance) by passing instance to the Javascript function.

now take a look at Test function. I am trying to call Java function named "updateImageContent" from there.The syntax written according GWT documentation.

When I run the application the instance of "testscan" class is Null what can be the reason?

```
public class testscan implements EntryPoint {
private Image image_0 = new Image("home.gif");
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("main_panel");
    rootPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE);

    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    rootPanel.add(verticalPanel, 5, 5);
    verticalPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    verticalPanel.add(horizontalPanel);
    horizontalPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    Image image_1 = new Image("home.gif");
    horizontalPanel.add(image_1);
    image_1.setSize("180px", "180px");

    horizontalPanel.add(image_0);
    image_0.setSize("180px", "180px");

    Image image_2 = new Image("home.gif");
    horizontalPanel.add(image_2);
    image_2.setSize("180px", "180px");

    Button btnScan = new Button("Scan");
    verticalPanel.add(btnScan);

    btnScan.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            x();
        }
    });

}
public void x()
{
    Test(this);

}

public native void Test(testscan instance) /*-{
    instance.@com.sflpro.testscan.client.testscan::updateImageContent()();
}-*/;

public void updateImageContent()
{
    Window.alert("ok");
    //String s = scanFileContent();
    //Window.alert(s);
    if(image_0==null)
        Window.alert("bad");
    else
        Window.alert("good");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the way your ClickHandler is implemented as an anonymous inner class. At the point when `Test` method is executed, `this` has no meaning anymore. You need to rewrite your ClickHandler to hold an instance to your class:

```
public class testscan implements EntryPoint {
public static class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
   testscan instance;
   public MyClickHandler(testscan instance) {
      this.instance = instance;
   }

   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            this.instance.x();
   }
}
private Image image_0 = new Image("home.gif");
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("main_panel");
    rootPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.RELATIVE);

    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    rootPanel.add(verticalPanel, 5, 5);
    verticalPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    verticalPanel.add(horizontalPanel);
    horizontalPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    Image image_1 = new Image("home.gif");
    horizontalPanel.add(image_1);
    image_1.setSize("180px", "180px");

    horizontalPanel.add(image_0);
    image_0.setSize("180px", "180px");

    Image image_2 = new Image("home.gif");
    horizontalPanel.add(image_2);
    image_2.setSize("180px", "180px");

    Button btnScan = new Button("Scan");
    verticalPanel.add(btnScan);

    btnScan.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler(this));

}
public void x()
{
    Test(this);

}

public native void Test(testscan instance) /*-{
    instance.@com.sflpro.testscan.client.testscan::updateImageContent()();
}-*/;

public void updateImageContent()
{
    Window.alert("ok");
    //String s = scanFileContent();
    //Window.alert(s);
    if(image_0==null)
        Window.alert("bad");
    else
        Window.alert("good");

}
}
```

I mean this whole way you are going about it is a bit strange, but I understand you are just learning and this is just a test app you are playing around with. Normally you wouldn't have this type of code in your EntryPoint class.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how your code changes anything: the x() call in Vasil's code is actually testscan.this.x() (the anonymous inner class has an implicit reference to its parent testscan instance, which is equivalent to using a 'static' nested class initialized explicitly with the testscan instance), so there's no reason it wouldn't work (apart from a bug in the GWT compiler optimizations, which your code might not trigger)

Comment: You are right, I think it is a bug. This code running in java with normal java methods should work. I wonder if it should work in hosted mode as well. I didn't test the code that I wrote but if it is a bug in GWT as you said it shouldn't trigger it because there is a reference to "this" in the click handler. Could the compiler be running into the common Javascript mistake with closures?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think it's a bug in GWT. do you have any suggestion workaround for this kind of tasks?

Comment: Well the code that I wrote should work. But why are you calling the Test method like that? It's an instance method, so using "this" inside it should work. Or you tried it and it didn't?

Comment: I tried the code you sent but it's also not working. Actually in real application I need to communicate from external application(let's say external javascript) with GWT application. I tried to make test project first and noticed it's not working. Need some callback mechanism with my External App.